# Python 3.7 - Printing list of NumPy arrays prints "array" in front of the actual arrays. Why?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm new to programming and have practically no grasp on terminology, so please excuse me for any basic questions I might have.

I'm trying to list an array of arrays.

I have written a function over a 2D array that lists the highest value in the array and the points where it occurs. These points (maxima) form arrays `[i,j]` which, for ease of display, I want to collect into a single numpy array or list `max_p`. To my knowledge, the most sensible way to do that is with `numpy.append( max_p, [i,j] )`. The issue with this is that it *merges* `[i,j])` into the `max_p` array so that I get an array of single values instead of ordered pairs. So I decided to convert the whole thing into a list.

This worked well, for the most part- I got my list of ordered pairs I can print off in a single line.

However, the arrays in the big list `max_p`are not printed as, say `[a,b]`. They're printed as `array([a,b])`. This happens regardless of whether I use `max_p.tolist()` or `list(max_p)`.

And, of course, since none of this is meaningful without the actual code, here it is:

```
def maxfinder_2D(array):
    maxima_array = numpy.array([]) # placeholder array
    for i in range(0, 422): # side note: learn how to get dim.s of 
                            # a multidimensional array
        x_array = array [i,:] # set array to be the i-th row
       # row_max = numpy.append(row_maxfinder_1D(x_array))
        maxima_array = numpy.append(maxima_array, numpy.array([maxfinder_1D(x_array)]))
            # We construct a new array, maxima_array, to list the 
            # maximum of every row in the plot.
            # The maximum, then, must be the maximum of this array.
    max_2D = maxfinder_1D(maxima_array)
    print("The maximum value in the image is: ", max_2D)
    global max_p
    max_p = []
    # This gives us the maximum value. Finding its location is another
    # step, though I do wish I could come up with a way of finding the
    # location and the maximum in a single step.
    for i in range(0,422): 
        for j in range(400): # the nested loop runs over the entire array
            val = img[i][j]
            if val == max_2D:
                max_pos_array = numpy.array([])
                max_pos_array = numpy.append(max_pos_array , i)
                max_pos_array = numpy.append(max_pos_array , j)
                list(max_pos_array)
                    #print(max_pos_array.tolist())
                max_p.append(max_pos_array)
    return max_2D
print("The function attains its maximum of ",maxfinder_2D(img)," on ", max_p)
```

And here is (part of) the output:

`The maximum value in the image is:  255.0 The function attains its maximum of  255.0  on  [array([200., 191.]), array([200., 192.]), array([201., 190.]), array([201., 193.]), array([202., 190.]), array([202., 193.]), array([203., 193.]), array([204., 191.]),`...

I want the arrays to show up as simply, for example, `[200. , 191.]`.

Why does this "artifact" occur? Does it have something to do with how numpy relates arrays to lists?

**EDIT: As it turns out all I needed to do was to treat max_pos_array as a list as well, but I'm still curious about why, exactly, this happens.**

Comment: Because that's how `numpy.ndarray.__repr__` is defined... I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I have no idea what `.__repr__` even means.

Comment: When you `print(some_object)`, the actual `str` object that is being printed is the string returned by either `__str__` or `__repr__`. [See this question for the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr). In any case, the main point is, *because that's how it's designed to work*. Whoever designed `numpy` could have had `print(my_array)` print `banana` or `foo` if they *wanted*.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python objects have `repr` and `str` display methods

```
In [1]: x = np.arange(3)
In [2]: x
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [3]: repr(x)
Out[3]: 'array([0, 1, 2])'
In [4]: str(x)
Out[4]: '[0 1 2]'
In [5]: print(x)
[0 1 2]
```

For a list, they are the same, `[,]` for the list itself and `repr` for the elements:

```
In [6]: alist = [x]
In [7]: alist
Out[7]: [array([0, 1, 2])]
In [8]: repr(alist)
Out[8]: '[array([0, 1, 2])]'
In [9]: str(alist)
Out[9]: '[array([0, 1, 2])]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with a string representation of your array

```
print("The function attains its maximum of ",maxfinder_2D(img)," on ", np.array2string(max_p))
```